# Change property in Backbone.model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to understand  Backbone.
How get previous value when change property in model??

```
<div id="sidebar">Color</div>
        <script>

$(function () {
   var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  promptColor: function() {
    var cssColor = prompt("change property");
    this.set({color: cssColor});
  }
});

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

sidebar.on('change:color', function() {

    //How get previous value??



  $('#sidebar').css({background: this.get('color') || 'orange'});
});



sidebar.promptColor();

});
```

How do I know the value before the change?Thank`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method you are looking for: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previous